# Cubase Essential 5 no sound

Tags: cubase

my Cubase Essential 5 is all working on my PC and I can see the midi keyboard is inputting music when I play it, but I can’t hear anything. Computer monitors etc are all working fine normally so I suspect it’s something very simple I haven’t activated or whatever. Can anyone help? Please email nickpease@aol.com. Thanks

Comment: I’m not a Cubase guy but DAW’s have a place in audio settings or preferences where you assign the audio in and out. Look for it and make sure the correct output is assigned.

Comment: It might be that cubase has exclusive access to the output asio device. There is possibly a setting that allows it to be shared.

Comment: I don't know if you're new to Cubase or MIDI, so this might seem obvious. Have you set up a MIDI track and assigned an instrument or synth to it? The MIDI controller is simply sending a command to play a note, it doesn't carry any sound itself. I appreciate this is a fairly old post, but it might help others.